# Java Chatbox appending additional white space

Tags: java, textarea

I have a simple Chatbox that has the following code:

```
public class Chatbox extends JFrame
{
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JTextArea inputField;
    JTextArea chatTextArea;
    JLabel chatLabel;
    boolean typing;
    Timer t;

    public Chatbox()
    {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        // Set frame properties
        setTitle("Plain Text Editor - <ID>");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create a JPanel and set layout
        mainPanel=new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));


        // Create JTextField, add it.
        inputField=new JTextArea();

        //inputField.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        inputField.setLineWrap(true);

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(inputField, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        mainPanel.add(sp);

        // Add panel to the south,
        add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        // Add a KeyListener
        inputField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
            {    
                // If he presses enter, add text to chat textarea
                if(ke.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) showLabel(inputField.getText());
            }


        });

        // Create a textarea
        chatTextArea=new JTextArea();

        // Make it non-editable
        chatTextArea.setEditable(false);

        // Set some margin, for the text
        chatTextArea.setMargin(new Insets(7,7,7,7));

        chatTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        chatTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);


        // Set a scrollpane
        JScrollPane js=new JScrollPane(chatTextArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);  
        add(js);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent we)
            {
                // Get the focus when window is opened
                inputField.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        setSize(400,400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showLabel(String text)
    {
        // If text is empty return
        if(text.trim().isEmpty()) return;

        // Otherwise, append text with a new line
        chatTextArea.append(text+"\n");

        // Set textfield and label text to empty string
        inputField.setText("");
    }
}
```

However, there is an additional space being appended when I press enter into the TextArea. How can I make it so that messages are being appended separately without an additional white white space?

I'm also not sure if the JScrollPane is messing up the spacing as this issue was not happening before I implemented the JScrollPane.

Comment: `inputField.addKeyListener` is a bad idea, use a `ActionListener` instead

Comment: Try reversing `chatTextArea.append(text+"\n");` so that the new line prefixes the text

Answer (score 0):

`chatTextArea.append(text+"\n");` is appending a new line every time you add new text.

Instead, you might consider prefixing the text with a new line (when text already exists in the chat window), for example...

```
private void showLabel(String text) {
    // If text is empty return
    if (text.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    if (!chatTextArea.getText().isEmpty()) {
        text = "\n" + text;
    }

    // Otherwise, append text with a new line
    chatTextArea.append(text);

    // Set textfield and label text to empty string
    inputField.setText("");
}
```

A additional new line will also be coming from your input `JTextArea` (which took me some time to realise as I was expecting a `JTextField` )

This occurs because the `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` will most likely be processed by the `JTextArea` (and its underlying `Document`) before your `KeyListener`, which means the new line is now actually part of the text.

You might consider trimming the text before you send it to the `showLabel` method, for example...

```
inputField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        // If he presses enter, add text to chat textarea
        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            showLabel(inputField.getText().trim());
        }
    }
});
```

How ever, a better solution would be to try and remove and white space at the end of the `String` manually, as `trim` will remove leading and trailing white space, but I'll leave you to figure that out

Comment: Appreciate the response. I do believe the `JTextArea` is my problem as you pointed out. It seems that every example online uses `JTextField` as the chat input. The reason for my use of a `JTextArea` is I want to allow the user multiple lines to edit their message before sending. Kind of like what I'm doing as I type this message. I noticed also when I full screen this chat application after sending a message or two, the `JTextArea` cursor defaults to the 2nd line, so that may be the problem? If not that, I will try to come up with a solution as you mentioned at the end of your response.